# Third party tools in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, xcodegen

I am new to teamcity, I am generating xcode project using xcodegen. After spending time on few articles, I concluded some of the suggestion are to add xcodegen in agent requirements or install xcodegen on build agent and write script in build step.
Similarly, I want to use a (xcov)third party tool to generate code coverage reports.

Can some one please help me to understand how to work with third party tools in teamcity.

Comment: share your code first, possible some error messages

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.